# fmt:formatDate not working as expected

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to format a java.util.Date object, that I am getting in my jsp, into a pattern of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" but it still prints it in a different (default probably) format.

I have included the taglibrary using this statement -

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
```

and I am printing this as a value in a cell of a table using the following code line -

```
<td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" value="${proposal.creationDate}"/></td>
```

But it still prints as the following -

```
Wed May 24 00:00:00 IST 3911
```

Can someone please suggest, what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: try adding `type="date"` as attribute

Answer (score 15):

I had this same problem.  I was able to fix it by setting a locale before attempting to format the date:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

This fixed the problem, but I don't know why.

Comment: Since I've posted this, I have learned why this works.  The format operations (fmt:formatDate and fmt:formatNumber) default to using `.toString()` if locale is NULL, even if an explicit format has no conversions that are locale dependent.  Depending on the setup of your appserver there may be no default locale, leaving it NULL.

Comment: An alternative to the fmt:setLocale tag is to set the Locale from the servlet with javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config.set(request, Config.FMT_LOCALE, new Locale("en", "US"));

Comment: I had the same problem. The tag was trying to find a locale, eventually reaching the request where it would look at the `accept-language` request header for a fallback locale value. As only a few request headers were being white-listed, this failed which lead to `.toString()` being used. It's worthwhile debugging `FormatDateSupport` to see how it attempts to find a locale to use when formatting!

Answer (score 1):

That will happen when the `${proposal.creationDate}` **actually** returns a `String` instead of a fullworthy [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Fix it accordingly.

```
private Date creationDate;

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}
```

If you really can't change the type for some unobvious reason, then you need to parse it first by [`<fmt:parseDate>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/parseDate.html).

```
<fmt:parseDate var="realCreationDate" value="${proposal.creationDate}" pattern="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" locale="en" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${realCreationDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
```

But that's plain hacky.

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, hours are to be represented by `HH` not `hh`. See also [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The year 3911 instead of 2011 in the printout also suggests that you've used the **deprecated** `Date` constructor/methods to create it.

Comment: type is java.util.Date as when I try to print $(proposal.creationDate.class}, it gives Date. Also, my bean's getter returns a Date too.

Comment: Well, apparently you're not running the JSP/JSTL code you think you're running. Rebuild/redeploy/restart. Create if necessary a minimalistic JSP file with just a `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %><jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" /><fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />`

Comment: We are using web-app version 2.4, could it have anything to do with it?

Comment: Servlet 2.4 requires JSTL 1.1 (which exist of 2 files), not JSTL 1.2 (which exist of 1 file). See also our JSTL wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info. Regardless, does the minimalistic test JSP work? Just paste the code in previous comment in a `test.jsp` and run it.

Comment: Unfortunately, even that returns - "Tue May 31 20:11:51 IST 2011"

Comment: Your classpath is apparently dirty. Maybe you've mixed different JSTL versions or something. Cleanup it. Put the right libs at the right places.